# How to check if the CSS background-color is white?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I need this:

```
$('*').each(function() {
        if($(this).css("background-color") == "#ffffff") {
           $(this).css("background-color") == "#000000"
        }
    });​​​​
```

to work onclick of an  class.

Comment: how to do this is trivially discovered with some google.com and jquery.com searching.

Comment: There is a better way than this. Please explain some more of your exact issue so we can help

Comment: I think this is a fairly good question (it is not a "trivial answer" as one might expect), but it lacks important information, mainly: **a description of the problem and/or what "doesn't work"** - Please add it :) Also, I would recommend using stylesheets and/or CSS classes, if at all an option. It will be faster and more maintainable.

Comment: (And, please post a *minimal* test-case and perhaps a http://jsfiddle.net; in this case note that the "onclick" is a secondary issue and should not have been mentioned at all since it is not even remotely present in the given code.)

Answer (score 5):

Even if it were correct (it's not), it would be unreliable and unlikely to work. The reason for that is that there are several ways of showing a white colour:

- `white`
- `#ffffff` and all 64 case combinations thereof
- `#fff` and all 8 case combinations thereof
- `rgb(255,255,255)` and all ∞ combinations of arbitrary whitespace between values
- `rgba(255,255,255,1)` and all ∞ combinations of arbitrary whitespace between values

You could check it this way:

```
if( $(this).css("background-color").match(/^(?:white|#fff(?:fff)?|rgba?\(\s*255\s*,\s*255\s*,\s*255\s*(?:,\s*1\s*)?\))$/i))
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but there must be a way to get the (numerical) color value in a saner manner .. also http://jsfiddle.net/hSn9m/ seems to indicate that - at least in Safari (latest), FF 18, and IE 9 - it is normalized. But, I have no idea what this behavior is elsewhere or how it is defined to work.

Comment: @pst Some browsers (mostly more recent ones) do normalise it to `rgb()` format for opaque colours, and `rgba()` for translucent ones. However, older browsers do not. This is a cross-browser answer.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ makes reference to "Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)." .. what a pity that this is so (and that jQuery doesn't normalize it) :(

Comment: I think you are missing a question mark right after `(?:,\s*1\s*)`

Comment: @THelper Indeed I am. Well spotted.

Comment: Thanks for this. I added HSL support: 
/^(?:white|#fff(?:fff)?|rgba?\(\s*255\s*,\s*255\s*,\s*255\s*(?:,\s*1\s*)?\)|hsla?\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*,\s*100\s*(?:,\s*1\s*)?\))$/i