# jQuery not changing element background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I am using

```
$(function () {

var one = $('h1');
var two = $('#mainNav img');

if (one.css('color') ==='rgb(12,74,164)') 
{
    two.css('background-color', '#6e6C80');
};

});
```

to check the if the color of a certain element is the needed one and then change the color of another element. It has no effect. I found that the color I'm checking for needs to be converted to rgb but it doesn't help. What am I missing?

Comment: can you share the HTML.

Comment: [This solves your problem....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741291/how-to-check-if-the-css-background-color-is-white)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the spaces in RGB

```
$(function () {

var one = $('h1');
var two = $('#mainNav img');

if (one.css('color') ==='rgb(12, 74, 164)') 
{
    two.css('background-color', '#6e6C80');
};

});
```